# Server error from else if condition

Tags: php

I keep getting a server error and I have limited it down to this code block.  I must not be familiar with syntax.  Can someone point out why I am getting a server error?? I posted all the code.  HERE IT IS.....

```
<?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['userid'];

//this connects to the database
$con = mysql_connect("example","example","example");
mysql_select_db("example", $con);

 //this is the info the user entered stored as variables
 $leaguename = $_POST["leaguename"];
 $members = $_POST["members"];
 $leaguepassword = $_POST["leaguepassword"];

  //this filters throught the variables to check against mysql injections
 $leaguename = (filter_var($leaguename, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
 $leaguename = (filter_var($leaguename, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 $members = (filter_var($members, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
 $members = (filter_var($members, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 $leaguepassword = (filter_var($leaguepassword, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
 $leaguepassword = (filter_var($leaguepassword, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

 //this is the variables that displays errors 
 $errors = ""; 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM League_Info WHERE League = '$leaguename'"); 
 $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $result3 = $result2['League'];

 $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM League_Info WHERE User_ID = '$id'");
 $result5 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);
 $result6 = $result5['User_ID'];

 if ($id == "") {
    $errors .= "<li>You must register or login to create a league!"; break;
  } elseif ($result3 != "") {
    $errors .= "<li>League Name already in use!"; break;
  } elseif ($result6 != "") {
    $errors .= "<li>You already have a league!"; break;
  } else {
 }

 // no errors
 if ($errors == "") {
    $sql="INSERT INTO League_Info (League, User_ID, Commissioner, Year, Members, League_Password) 
        VALUES('$leaguename', '$id', 'y', '2012', '$members', '$leaguepassword')"; 
    mysql_query($sql);
        /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/invite.php");
    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;

 } else {
 }

 ?>

 <html><head><title>Create a League</title></head>

<body>

<center><h1>Create a League</h1></center>

<center>
<div class="form" style= "width:500px; height:200px; background-color:gray; ">
<form action="createleaguevalidation.php" method="POST">
League Name:       <input style="margin-left:0px;" type="text" name="leaguename" value="<?=$leaguename?>" /><br />
Number of Members: <input type="text" name="members" value="<?=$members?>"/><br>
League Password:   <input type="password" name="leaguepassword" value="<?=$leaguepassword?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create League" name="action">
<input type="reset"  value="Reset">
</form>

<div style="background-color:#ffcccc; height:80px; width:500px;">
<?=$errors?>
</div>

</div>
<center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We'll be able to help you much better if you include the actual error that you received.

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: @FaceBook: find your server logs.  PHP has written a fuller error message somewhere.

Comment: Downvoted because of bad code sample, will revoke when fixed.

Comment: dude this is the only code that is relevant.  i can post it all but i guarantee it won't help. please don't downvote me...

Comment: Well is it in a loop or not? You haven't made it clear.

Comment: if your `else` block really is empty, then it is useless and you should remove it.

Comment: @FaceBook: you're posting a lot of comments, but not answering people's questions.

Comment: Did you read the manual page for [break](http://php.net/break)?

Comment: I actually figured it out.  I just added a while(true) loop before.  Thanks for the help.  Sorry for any pain... :(

Comment: Remove your useless `while(true)`, and remove your useless `break`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this code isn't inside a loop, then `break` is an error.

Comment: then how would i exit when it meets a given condition??

Comment: this is all the relevant code I have.  I guess I should put it in a loop but i dont know how i would do it exactly

Comment: @FaceBook: this can't be all the code you have, and "relevant" is often hard to gauge.  What do you want to exit from?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, just take out `break;`

To break the loop, put `break;` at the end of all the if statements.

Comment: but i want to break the loop if it meets that condition

Comment: Is the if statement inside a loop?

Comment: @FaceBook: were we supposed to guess that this was in a loop?  Post more code, and especially, the actual error message...

Comment: i don't have it in a loop.  is that what I should do?? how would I do that??